# VBA To Filter Access Table Using Criteria from ListBox on a Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access Data Base with data in a 180 columns table (groups) and a form (Log Selection Form) with a Multiselect list box (Listbox1). The listbox contains the titles of all columns (Groups).

I need to filter the groups Table with the selected log names from the listbox. I have a code but does not filter the table. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
    Option Compare Database

    Sub LoadData()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Str1 As String
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim mySQL As String
    Dim qryName As String
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Log Selection"
    Set frm = Forms("Log Selection")
    Set ctl = frm.Listbox1

    Z = frm.Listbox1.ItemsSelected.Count
    qryName = "Search Results"
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("Search Results", mySQL)
    
    
    For Each ItemIndex In frm.Listbox1.ItemsSelected
    Str1 = frm.Listbox1.ItemData(ItemIndex)

    mySQL = "SELECT Str1 FROM " & "[Groups] WHERE Len(Str1) > 0;"
    qdf.SQL = mySQL
    Next
    End Sub
```

I tried the attached VBA code
I expected a filter Query

Answer (score 0):

Str1 is a variable and cannot be embedded in SQL statement - concatenate.

This code assumes there is only one field selected from listbox.

`mySQL = "SELECT [" & Str1 & "] FROM [Groups] WHERE Len([" & Str1 & "]) > 0;"`

Comment: This is terrific solution Thank you so much. I found a piece of code which works fine for me except I need to modify the following statement to where Len(Selected item) > 0   ( strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Groups " & _
             "WHERE Groups.Region IN(" & strCriteria & ");")